# MatchCollection and Regex Matches weird behaviour

Tags: c#, regex

When I try to use a Regex to split a string the MatchCollection returned by `.Matches` only contain the string it self and not the group.

So here is my regex : `string pattern = @"^(\w[.])\s*(\w+)$";`

and a sample string : `W.Test`

I expect the MatchCollection to have 2 elements `W.` and `Test` but it looks like it doesnt work.

Comment: There is no problem with your regex. Something you have to do in the code itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to return the matched context from your capturing groups. The [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property gets the captured groups within the regular expression.

```
string pattern = @"^(\w[.])\s*(\w+)$";
string input = "W.Test";

Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);

if (match.Success) {
 Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); //=> 'W.'
 Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[2].Value); //=> 'Test'
}
```

Comment: Thanks that work (this will help me a lot now !) Also is there anyway to get only the first match? I mean my regex will only catch one match and I don't think using a foreach is really usefull

Comment: @PeterFour Yes that simple =)

Comment: Well explained, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Match match = Regex.Match(input, @" ^(?<firstGroup>\w[.])\s*(?<SecondGroup>\w+)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

var firstGroup = match.Groups["firstGroup"].Value
```